# How do you make a window full screen using the kivy design language?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Can someone tell me how to set a kivy window to full screen mode using the design language?

The result I'm looking for is either bordered full screen/border-less full screen. If you run the following example you'll see exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.app import App

class ExampleClass(Widget):
    pass



class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
       return ExampleClass()


Window.fullscreen = 'auto'
ExampleApp().run()

'''
   If you've never run it with that setting before. Be ready for borderless
   Full screen output.It can be scary the first time you see it lol :D
'''
```

An example of the code I'm working with is as follows.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Canvas
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.config import Config


class StartScreen(Screen):

    def Mute_Audio(self):
        pass


    def new_g(self):
        pass




    def l_g(self):
        pass


    def Settings(self):
        pass  



class SelectionScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
MyScreenManager:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    StartScreen:
    SelectionScreen:

<StartScreen>:
    name: 'start_screen'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size



    Button:
        id: b_1
        pos: 330,350
        size_hint:  0.2, 0.1
        text: 'button 1'
        font_size: 18
        on_press: root.new_g()
        on_release: app.root.current = 'selection_screen'


    Button:
        id: b_2
        pos: 330, 280
        size_hint:  0.2, 0.1
        text: 'button_2'
        font_size: 18


    Button:
        id: settings
        pos: 330, 210
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
        text: 'Settings'
        font_size: 18


    Button:
        id: mute_button
        pos:658, 495     
        size_hint: 0.2, 0.2







<SelectionScreen>:
    name: 'selection_screen'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos

''')

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Save me Stack Overflow'
        return root_widget

ExampleApp().run()
```

to reiterate, I need help setting the window to full screen using the design language. I just have no idea how to set it to full screen with kv.

UPDATE:

To re-iterate. I don't care about the positioning of widgets or how the full screen looks. All I need to know is how to set a Window to full screen mode using the design language aka KV.

I showed two examples. The first example shows what I want to do. In that it shows a border-less full screen window. The second example illustrates an example of the design language. I need to achieve the same result produced in the first example in the second example but instead of doing it in straight python I need to do it in the design language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems **it is possible to do it from the KV file**! (using **setattr**)

some kv file:

```
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window

<RootWidget>:
     some_property: setattr(Window, 'fullscreen' , 'auto')  or 'real_value!'
```

It is *hackish* though...